# C++ Filter Pipeline

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pipeline

I want to develop a Filter Pipeline for my Application.
The Pipeline should consist of any number of filters.

For the Filters i declare an abstract base class like this:

```
struct AbstractFilter {
    virtual void execute(const std::string& message) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractFilter() = default;
}
```

Each Filter should inherit from this base class and implement the `execute` Method.
Like so:

```
struct PrintMessage : public AbstractFilter {
    void execute(const std::string& message) override {
        std::cout << "Filter A " << message << '\n';
        //hand over message to next Filter

    }
}

struct Upper : public AbstractFilter {
    void execute(const std::string& message) override {
        std::string new_line;
        for (char c : line)
           new_line.push_back(std::toupper(c));
        //hand over message to next Filter
    }
}

struct WriteToFile : public AbstractFilter {
    void execute(const std::string& message) override {
        std::ofstream of{"test.txt"};
        of << message;
        of.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

The Message should be send from one filter to the next in the Pipeline.
If the pipeline for example is like this:

Upper -- PrintMessage -- WriteToFile

The Message should pass all the 3 Filters. (For example if `Upper` finished his work the message should be send to `PrintMessage` and so on)

In the example above if the Message `Hello World` is send to the Pipeline the output should be:

```
Console:
HELLO WORLD
test.txt:
HELLO WORLD
```

**EDIT 2:**

The Filter only changes the content of the given Message. The Type is not changed. Every Filter should work with for example strings or a given class.
The Message is only forwarded to one recipient.

My Question is now how to connect these Filters?

My First guess was to use `Queues`. So every Filter gets an `Input` and `Output` Queue. For this i think every filter should run inside it's own `Thread` and be notified if data is added to his `Input` Queue. (The `Output` Queue of for example FilterA is also the `Input` Queue of FilterB)

My Second Guess was to use the Chain Of Responsibility Pattern and `boost::signals2`
So FilterB for example connects to the Signal of FilterA. FilterA calls these Filter when it finished it's work.

Which of the two solutions is the more flexible? Or is there even a better way to connect the Filters?

An additional Question is it also possible to run the whole Pipeline inside a Thread so that i can start multiple Pipelines? (In the Example have 3 of the FilterA-FilterB-FilterD Pipeline up and running?)

Comment: There's a nice example in Boost Asio: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/example/cpp14/executors/pipeline.cpp (also c++11 https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/example/cpp11/executors/pipeline.cpp)

Comment: This might be a good candidate for coroutines if you have a compiler that supports it.  I think coroutines are C++20

Comment: Yes i also thought about using them but Unfortunately i could not use a compiler with c++20.

Comment: Your filters don't modify what they are given at all, so I wouldn't call them filters. Also, why force people to implement another baseclass when there's just one function? `std::function` provides enough abstraction. That said, I don't understand your requirements, i.e. what behaviour do you need? Do you need an ordering? Can any stage terminate the pipeline?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry maybe the examples are not so good. Some Filter should also be able to modify the message before handing them over. I have updated the examples.

Comment: In your code, it's the filter's responsibility to hand it over to the next filter. I'd rather return the changed message. Then however, I need to ask again: Is it just the content of the message or also the type that changes? Also, I'm wondering if one filter can forward to more than one other filter as well? The case that it doesn't forward anything seems to be obviously necessary but if there are multiple recipients, then it seems that thinking about events and event listeners would be a better approach. Can you provide a real usage example?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's only the content of the message thats changes. Not the type. Every filter should operate on the same type (string or maybe a class). The forward is only to one recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would procede in this way:
create a List with all the implemented versions of the Abstract Filter. So, following your exmample, after reading the input file I will get a list with:

```
[0]:Upper 
[1]:PrintMessage
[2]:WriteToFile
```

Then a single thread (or a thread poll if you need to process many string at time) waiting a string in an input queue. When a new string appears in the pool, the thread loops on the filter list and at the end posts the result in an output queue.

If you want to run it in parallel, you need to find a way to keep the order of the input strings anche nelle stringhe di output.

Comment: I’m afraid our Italian isn’t up to par.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Chain of Responsibility pattern is simpler, allows for cleaner code and greater flexibility.

You do not need third-party libraries to implement it.
What you call filters are actually *handlers*. All handlers implement a common interface, defining a single method that could be named `handle()` and could even take an object as parameter to share state. Each handler stores a pointer to the next handler. It may or may not call that method on it; in the latter case processing is halted, and it acts as a *filter*.

Running pipeline stages in parallel is more involved if some of them require the output of others as input. For different pipelines to run in parallel, each one would run on its own thread, and you could use a queue to pass inputs to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think AbstractFilter is not necessary and I'd suggest to use std::tuple to define a pipeline:

```
std::tuple<FilterA, FilterB> pipeline1;
std::tuple<FilterA, FilterB, FilterC ... > pipeline2;
```

To run a message through a pipeline do (using c++17):

```
template<typename Pipeline>
void run_in_pipeline(const std::string& message, Pipeline& pipeline){
  std::apply([&message](auto&& ... filter) {
    (filter.execute(message), ...);
  }, pipeline);
}
```

If you care about performance and filters must be executed sequentially, I wouldn't suggest using multithreading or signal-slot patterns on a single pipeline. Consider instead run different pipelines on different threads if you are dealing with multithreading applications

Comment: Thanks for the reply the abstract filter was defined because I want the pipeline consist of different filter which could be defined in a config file so the pipeline should be created dynamically based on the configuration

Comment: @Kevin  So if it has the be runtime configurable then a pipeline would be a vector of pointers to abstract filters?  The actual run_in_pipeline would be a for loop.  If you want to avoid the pointer to object for performance reasons then something else will be needed because even std::function dynamically allocates memory internally..